# When using hide my email for registering a subscription

Tags: icloud, email

Has anyone tried to use an Apple "hide my email" email to register for something? The option was offered to me, and so I took it and then added a password. So far so good, I received the confirmation forewarded to me.

But...

Wehn I go back to that site, if it asks me to log in again for some reason, do I need to go look up my fake email in iCloud every time? And did Safari save my password?

I think that use case doesn't work. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

If you register with a "hide my email" address that will be your email address on the service. The service is not aware of your "actual" iCloud address (that's the whole idea behind it, really), which means you will use your generated email address to log in, etc.

The keychain works in the same way as usual. The combination of email and password is saved for the URL. This can be your actual iCloud, a generated address or any 3rd party address you're using - whichever you entered.

If a login was not saved or you forgot your generated address you can look it up in System Preferences > Apple ID, then click on "options" next to "Hide my email" where you will find a list of all generated addresses with a description of the service or URL they were generated for.

Comment: And to clarify, you can save this autogenerated email to your Safari password manager (or any other password manager) so you don't have to remember it

Answer (score 0):

Hide my email is not single sign on. It just sets up a mail alias so the company doesn’t know your iCloud log in.

Did the service offer **Sign in with Apple**? If so, you get the secure sign in SSO plus optional secure alias if you chose that.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210318

If it was not **Sign in with Apple**, you’d need to understand how the service you signed up with handles passwords to get it saved or reset.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210425

I’ve used both and so far am very happy. I still am nervous I won’t click hide my email and divulge my AppleID which I traditionally only give to close friends and family and use other emails for everything else commercial or non-trusted with an existing human relationship already established.